# Fitting a GAM with a count response variable across multiple years

Tags: r, poisson-distribution, generalized-additive-model

I am trying to fit a GAM where the response variable is a count. For my particular problem, I have counts for a species, across a number of different years. So it would seem to me that the best thing to do would be to generate a mean across the three years, and use this as the response variable. However this doesn't work when the GAM is configured to use a poisson distribution; presumably as this distribution only works with the integers?

Reproducible code as follows:

```
set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(count_y1 = rpois(100,1),
                  count_y2 = rpois(100,1),
                  count_y3 = rpois(100,1),
                  pred1 = rnorm(100, 10, 1), 
                  pred2 = rnorm(100, 0, 1), 
                  pred3 = rnorm(100, 0, 1), 
                  pred4 = rnorm(100, 0, 1))

library(dplyr)
dat <- dat %>% 
         rowwise() %>% 
         mutate(count_mn = mean(c(count_y1, count_y2, count_y3)))
```

If I set up the GAM as follows:

```
model <- gam(count_mn ~ s(pred1) + s(pred2) + s(pred3) + offset(pred4),
             data = dat, 
             family = poisson(link="log"), 
             method = "REML", 
             select = TRUE)
```

(in my real world problem I have an offset that handles a variable survey area for where the species count was taken). This gives the following output:

```
Error in if (abs(old.score - score) > score.scale * conv.tol) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

If I now assign `quasipoisson` to family, which I understand is used for zero-inflated and continuous response data, I get a model fit:

```
Family: quasipoisson 
Link function: log 

Formula:
count_mn ~ s(pred1) + s(pred2) + s(pred3) + offset(pred4)

Estimated degrees of freedom:
1.640 0.102 1.754  total = 4.5 

REML score: 54.81147
```

So my question would be, is it possible to fit the model across the three count years , using a poisson distribution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a sum across years, not a mean.  The sum of Poisson variables is Poisson; the mean isn't.

```
set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(count_y1 = rpois(100,1),
                  count_y2 = rpois(100,1),
                  count_y3 = rpois(100,1),
                  pred1 = rnorm(100, 10, 1), 
                  pred2 = rnorm(100, 0, 1), 
                  pred3 = rnorm(100, 0, 1), 
                  pred4 = rnorm(100, 0, 1))

library(dplyr)
dat <- dat %>% 
         rowwise() %>% 
         mutate(count_sm = sum(c(count_y1, count_y2, count_y3)))
```

and now your `gam` fits fine

```
model <- gam(count_sm ~ s(pred1) + s(pred2) + s(pred3) + offset(pred4),
             data = dat, 
             family = poisson(link="log"), 
             method = "REML", 
             select = TRUE)
summary(model)
```

You could also add another offset equal to log(3) so that the rest of the linear predictor is now a model for log(E[sum]/3) rather than log(E[sum])